# Custom hook with react - dont know whats wrong with this one?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying been more simlicity but i still learn the power of custom hook.
i'm trully not understand whats wrong with my hook.

```
const UseMessage = (msg: string, delay: number, cb?: () => void): [setCB: () => void] => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const setCB = () => {
    setMessage(() => msg);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setMessage(() => msg);
      if (typeof cb === "function") {
        cb();
      }
    }, delay);
  };

  return [setCB];
};

export default UseMessage;
```

i'm getting error :Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

Answer (score 0):

Custom hook names should always start with lower case `use` ([see beta docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#hook-names-always-start-with-use)), so change to `useMessage`.

Comment: Hook names must start with use followed by a capital letter, like useState, but its not the issue due to my other hooks works fine and i started them with UseSomthing ...

Comment: Can you make a reproduced sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which can resolve your problem, here:

1. First, name your hook with lowercase `use` and not uppercase. The reason for that is it is wrong according to the React docs.
2. Here, your `UseMessage` is not a custom hook for React, just a javascript function. Inside it, you are using `useState` which is a hook and React won't allow that. The reason is the next point.
3. Second, according to the rules of React you can utilise any hook only inside the body of a function component or inside the body of another hook function.